# Are /virtualization and /virtual-machine synonyms?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a tag [virtual-machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) and a tag [virtualization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization). I can't see any difference in usage between them, nor can I think of a reason why there should be, so I think they should be synonyms. Any objections?

---

Please synonymize [virtual-machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) → [virtualization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not technically synonymous, but usage does appear to be identical for both.

I'm OK with a synonym as long as [virtualization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization) is the "master" and [virtual-machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine) the synonym, virtualization being the more general term.